# Game Center swift

Tags: swift, game-center, swift3

I am having problem integrating Game Center and multiplayer in my app that is written in swift 3.I have looked at the tutorials on the web but they are written in swift 2 or objective c. May you help me by explaining me ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question is too broad. Please ask clear questions and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get help.

Comment: I have just found a nice tutorial on implementing leaderboards with GameKit framework, but I don 't know hot to add challenges in my quiz game using Swift 3.
Thank you